# Difference-frequency generation: physical interpretation

Tags: optics, non-linear-optics

Sum-frequency generation 
[image: sum-frequency generation]
is easy for my to understand. Two photons combine their energies in a nonlinear medium and out comes one photon with the sum of both energies.

But Difference-frequency generation
[image: difference-frequency generation]
is harder for me. For one thing, I'm struck by where the extra energy went? Is it heating up the nonlinear medium?

Is there a way for me to visualize this process that is similar to my understanding of the case of Sum-frequency generation?

Answer (score 1):

The DFG component in the wave equation is proportional to

$$E_{1}E_{2}^{\ast}e^{-i(\omega_{1}-\omega_{2})}$$

Interpretating the fields as quantum entities, one takes $E_{1}\propto a_{1}$ and $E_{2}^{\ast}\propto a_{2}^{\dagger}$. Thus the above term is

$$a_{1}a_{2}^{\dagger}e^{-i(\omega_{1}-\omega_{2})}$$

You can interpret this contribution as the destruction of one $\omega_{1}$ photon and creation of both $\omega_{2}$ and $\omega_{1}-\omega_{2}$ photons. The creation of the first one is stimulated by an input beam of the same frequency. You can clearly see that conservation of energy works.

Comment: I see. So to write a balanced equation, the diagram should show one omega3 and one omega2 photon coming out of the non-linear medium.

Comment: @psitae Two $\omega_{2}$. The book just focuses on the interesting beam, discarding all the others.